# Why perl tries to reload module when it is already loaded?

Tags: perl

I was trying to install `Carton` into local directory for my project and got error:

```
--> Working on Test::Deep
Fetching...
...
t/isa.t ..................... Can't locate Mojo/Base.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Mojo::Base module) (@INC contains: CODE(0x557913d006d0) t/lib /home/kes/.cpanm/work/1626520042.29670/Test-Deep-1.130/blib/lib /home/kes/.cpanm/work/1626520042.29670/Test-Deep-1.130/blib/arch /home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux /home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/local/lib/perl5 /home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/lib /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/site_perl/5.35.1/x86_64-linux /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/site_perl/5.35.1 /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/5.35.1/x86_64-linux /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/5.35.1 CODE(0x557913d00670) .) at /home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/lib/A.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/kes/work/projects/tucha/monkeyman/lib/A.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require at /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/5.35.1/base.pm line 138.
    ...propagated at /home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.35.1/lib/5.35.1/base.pm line 160.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/isa.t line 133.
```

This error occur because my application has `A` module, but `t/isa.t` defines already its own `package A` which is loaded into memory already.

```perl
# Test::Deep:t/isa.t:120
package A;

use Test::Deep;
@A::ISA = qw( Test::Deep );

{
  ::ok(A->isa("Test::Deep"), "U::isa says yes");
  ::ok(! A->isa("Test"), "U::isa says yes");
}


{
  package C;
  use base 'A';    # <<<< this cause error
}
```

But why `use base 'A'` tries to reload package A from disk while `package A` is already loaded into memory?

perl -v
5.35.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing the difference between *packages* and *modules*. A package is a namespace. A module is a file. It's easy to confuse them because by convention, the definition of the `Foo::Bar::Baz` namespace will be in file `Foo/Bar/Baz.pm`.

When you write:

```perl
use Foo::Bar::Baz;
```

Perl interprets that as two instructions:

1. Load the file `Foo/Bar/Baz.pm` if it's not already loaded.
2. Call the method `import` on the `Foo::Bar::Baz` namespace.

(And `use base 'Foo::Bar::Baz'` does similar, except instead of #2, it does some funky stuff with inheritance.)

So in your case, when you do `use base 'A'`, Perl will do #1 unless file `A.pm` is already loaded. Yes, you've already defined some stuff in the `A` namespace, but that doesn't matter.

A few different solutions for you.

### Trick Perl into thinking A.pm is already loaded

Adding this line somewhere before `use base 'A'` will trick Perl into thinking `A.pm` has already been loaded.

```perl
BEGIN { $INC{'A.pm'} = __FILE__ };
```

### use parent

Do this instead of `use base 'A'`:

```perl
use parent '-norequire', 'A';
```

`parent` is the more modern version of `base` and has a `-norequire` option to skip step #1.

### use neither base nor parent

All those modules are doing for you are setting the `@ISA` variable for you. You can do that yourself.

```perl
{
  package C;
  our @ISA = 'A';
}
```

Comment: I always thought that `use A` will load file only if `A` name space is undefined. Thanks for clear it. Also I do not understand about `funky stuff with inheritance` at your explanation

Comment: If you do `use base "Foo"` in `package Bar`, then base.pm will just load `Foo.pm` and set `@Bar::ISA = ("Foo")` — that's the funky inheritance stuff... mostly. If you're using fields.pm then base.pm will do weird complex stuff with that too. But nobody really uses fields.pm these days, so it's better to use parent.pm instead of base.pm, because parent.pm strips out all the fields.pm-related stuff.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning about `use Mojo::Base`